HIP RT option missing on Fedora 40 worstation in blender 4.1 and 4.2
I have an RX 7900xtx and I was able to activate HIP in the Blender preferences.
However I don't have the HIP RT (experimental) box, it doesn't appear. Neither in Blender 4.1 nor in 4.2.
I must have some missing packages under fedora but I don't know which ones.
How can I get it and use this option please.
Sincerely
